# Page to appear in content slider

Tags: html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have a question regarding simple CSS problem. 
The example can be found here: http://codepen.io/design8383/pen/AyEri

My question is that when the page loads, I want 'Slide1' to appear right-away, rather than click on 'Slide1'. I know its simple and yet I can't seem to find the solution as to how do I achieve that.

So right now, when page loads, we don't see any slide pages unless we click on the link. Can somebody tell me how can I change that so when the page load, 'Slide 1' appears right away(like a main page) and then click on different links to go to different sliders.

Much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple hack would be to use JavaScript to navigate to the `s1` anchor on startup.

```
window.location.hash = "s1"
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FlAyJ

But I'm not sure if JS is an option for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking more along with CSS, but I guess its ok to use JS as well. Thank a lot. It works great.

Comment: One more question, it seems like when I click on number 2 3 4 or 5. It jumps to show the window. Is there a way to disable the pagejump when click on different slider button

Comment: I think the problem is that you use anchor links. Btw, the it behaves differently in different browsers. You could rebuild it with JS. Also, please consider upvoting this answer and marking it as accepted.